# Auto Form Submit Working in Wordpress only Logged Users

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, form-submit

I am using the below code to execute when the page load. It is working fine. But. It is redirecting only when I logged the wordpress.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms['form_signup'].submit();
}
</script>
<body>

<form name="form_signup" action="https://signnupformregister.com/login.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="pw" name="pw" value="pass@e"><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="user" name="un" value="username@microsft.in"><br><br>
 
</form> 

</body>
```

When I refresh the page after logout, login page only showing and hidden values not pass to the post URL.

Answer (score -1):

This could be because of the plugins you added and the effect of their updates on the theme.
For instance, a security plugin may disable the REST-API option for users except for the admin.
You need to check the `function.php` and find the relevant authentication function there. Something similar to this condition `(! is_user_logged_in())` then throw error if the users is not logged in.

Comment: We are using Elementor and I have added this code in the Elementor itself.

Comment: this file is located in your theme folder.